# Live Chat Title Bar

Tags: visualforce, chat, livechattranscript

How to change the text of the LiveChat Title bar i.e the title bar of the window that pops up to the livechat agent when a customer request to chat?

I am unable to find any config in chat console.

Comment: Why u r not using embedded service?

Comment: Could you please enlighten?I am new to this livechat

Answer (score 0):

Search for 'embedded_svc.settings.defaultMinimizedText' in your code base or the chat code embedded at the site where chat is hosted. You can update it with the text you want. This will display to the users when agents are online. Refer the document- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_set_chat_text.htm